# How to do function callback in swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, callback

Before I start, I understand there are many similar questions to this one. However, I think a newer version of swift may have made them out of date, as they didn't seem to work for me.

Here is my problem: I need to pass a function as a parameter to another function(a callback). However, I cannot figure out how to do this in Swift 5.3.3(I am pretty sure that's my version)

I want to make a mac app that controls which of my many discord bots are running. My discord bots are python files whose execution never ends. Therefore, if I execute them using the shell from swift, that line of code will never end. Therefore, I want to execute each bot asynchronously so that the application will not freeze. I am currently doing this by making a `DispatchWorkItem`, then using `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:DispatchWorkItem)` to execute the bot. However, making a `DispatchWorkItem` requires a callback to the function to execute(I'm ignoring the other parameters which appear to be optional).

Here's something like what I am trying to do:

```swift
let workItem=DispatchWorkItem(**INSERT CALLBACK(to exec function defined below) HERE**)
DispatchQueue.main.async(workItem)
```

I haven't yet gotten it to run successfully. I have next to no experience in swift, so I don't have a super firm idea of what I am doing wrong. What should `\*\*INSERT CALLBACK(to exec function below) HERE\*\*` be replaced with in that code? Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Here are all relevant parts of my code:

```swift
 func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()

        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
    }
//for the record I did not write that function(got it from this site) and sort of vaguely understand it but not really

 func exec(){
                let result = shell("/usr/local/bin/python3.9 path/to/python/file")
                print(result)
            }

//this has been proven to work, it just freezes that app because the above function will never end. This is why I want it to be asynchronous
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of outright answering I first want to provide you with a brief understanding of a callback function.

To put it simply: In most modern programming languages, functions can be taken as arguments/parameters in another function:

```
function doHomework(subject, finishedHomework()) {
    print('Started my homework!');
}
```

In the simplified case above, doHomework is to start executing before, the callback function (finishedHomework).
If we then call it like this:

```
doHomework('IT', () -> { print('Finished my homework!); });
```

Or

```
finishedHomework() { print('Finished my homework!') }
doHomework('IT', finishedHomework);
```

We will see an output saying we have started our homework printed out on the initial line, and we have finished our homework on the line below.
I put it on one line so you can see how the brackets equate.
We do this because in the case that our first function has a delay in execution (ie. API call, complex calculation), it will still execute first and then the second function in that order.
Think of the execution of the callback as being dependant on the initial function; if we started our homework and something else happens to stop us, we won't finish it.

In Swift, I believe callbacks are also referred to as closure functions, usually paired with a completion handler which I won't get too much into for simplicity's sake.
Here is another example, but this time passing a value in Swift:

```
let closureFunction = {
    (x: Int) -> String in
    return "The number in our closure function is: \(x)."
  }
  func funky(callback: (x: Int) -> String) {
    callback(13)
  }
  funky(closureFunction) /** The number in our closure function is: 13. */
```

Remember, in Swift 5, we can still define a function like:

```
(String)->() // takes a String returns void
()->(String) // takes void returns a String
```

And the closure syntax usually takes the following form:
{ (parameters) -> return type in
statements
}

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code below but hopefully it is a good step for you in the right direction.

```
let shell = { 
    (_ command: String) -> String in
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()

        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
    }

    func exec(callback: (command: String) -> String) {
        let result = callback("/usr/local/bin/python3.9 path/to/python/file")
        print(result)
    }

    exec(shell)
```

I am unfamiliar with using the DispatchWorkItem so maybe think about taking a quick tutorial on the DispatchQueue basics and maybe even DispatchSemaphore.
Either way, I think this should be enough information for you to get your bot management underway, without getting someone to do your work for you.
It should be quite easy to add the callback as a DispatchQueueItem from here.

Let the community know if there are still issues you are facing.

[DispatchQueue in Swift 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmu0v_25pgc)

[DispatchGroups and Semaphores](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rJN_ECd1XM&t=10s)

Comment: Thanks so much, this answer is exactly what I needed! It appears that the callback worked, though it still is freezing the application, so I'll look more into it on the links you provided.

Comment: Awesome Nathan, that is both great and interesting  news. If the application is freezing, maybe take a look if it is stuck in a loop somewhere. Xcode has a wonderful debugger. Set your breakpoints and see exactly what is up. It could be something other than your queue. Please mark the answer correct if it is correct for this context. Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: I've fixed it since, I was running it on the wrong thread(the main one). I should have run it on one of the global threads, which made it work.